# Qt "Expected type-specifier" before "ClassName" In Remote Device

Tags: c++, qt, g++, embedded-linux, remote-debugging

First of all. I know that in this forum is exist similar topic, but I write this because my case is more difrent (I think so). I running this program on remote machine with MIPS arch.

**With what we have to do ?**

- Liberay Qt was compiled to MIPS arch
- Version Liberary Qt 4.8.7 is Embedded - mips
- Program is remote debuging from PC machine
- Cross Compiler is mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-g++ from OpenWRT BuildRoot
- Program contains two class **cos , czas** and **main** file
- Program should be display from qDebug at 1 secound communicate to console via signal and slot mechanizm in Qt

**main.c**

```
#include "czas.h"
#include "cos.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cos *objektcos;
    czas *objetczasu;

    objetczasu = new czas();
    objektcos = new cos();

    QObject::connect(&objetczasu , SIGNAL(timeout()) , &objektcos, SLOT(przerwanie()));

    objetczasu->setInterval(1000);
    objetczasu->start();

    cout << " Hello Program " <<  endl;

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // loop

    return a.exec();
}
```

The `cos` header file:

```
#ifndef COS_H
#define COS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>

class cos : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    cos();
    ~cos();

public slots:
    void przerwanie();
};

#endif // COS_H
```

The `cos` source file:

```
#include "cos.h"

cos::cos()
{
    qDebug() << "Konstruktor cos" << endl;
}

cos::~cos()
{
}

void cos::przerwanie()
{
    qDebug() << " Przerwanie " << endl;
}
```

The `czas` header file:

```
#ifndef CZAS_H
#define CZAS_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

class czas : public QTimer
{
public:
    czas();
    ~czas();
};

#endif // CZAS_H
```

The `czas` source file:

```
#include "czas.h"

czas::czas()
{
    qDebug() << "Konstruktor czas" << endl;
}

czas::~czas()
{
}
```

And my error. This is communicate from **Commpiler Comunicate**

> ./nienazwany/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   ../nienazwany/main.cpp:16:10: error: 'objektcos' was not declared in
>   this scope
>        cos *objektcos;
>             ^ ../nienazwany/main.cpp:21:21: error: expected type-specifier before 'cos'
>        objektcos = new cos();
>                         ../nienazwany/main.cpp:21:21: error: expected ';' before 'cos' Makefile:218: recipe for target 'main.o' failed make:
>   *** [main.o] Error 1

A also try create object on stos, but it did not help also.

Comment: probably you have a name collision between your class and the trigonometric function cos. Try changing your class name

Comment: My god ! what a stupid and easy mistake :/ Something similar never me happend. But maybe this topic was be usefull for another funny gay like me, which also call own class like. `cos, sin, sleep, usleep` and so on.  Thank You for help.